# Should I have a heading on every page?

Tags: website-design, title, page

I'm working on a project, and have ran into a little design problem.

I have a navbar right above the content.

I'm not sure if the page should have a heading on it.

I've given examples below.

With Heading:
[image: with heading]

Without Heading:
[image: without heading]

Answer (score 10):

I would include the heading for the following reasons:

- If you were to port this design to mobile, you may not be including the primary navigation at the top of the page, thus leaving no way for the user to determine what page they are on.
- It provides consistency across pages, and allows you to scale if you decide to put drop downs inside those primary menu items. In which case the user would not be able to the tell the current page title at a glance.
- Also how would the 'no-title' design hold up on auxiliary pages which don't have a prominent 'active' state within the primary navigation for users to use as the title of the page.
- Your heading could be used as your `<h1>` tag for the page.

Comment: Could it also depend on the page's content it's self?

I mean the Activity page will have things like graphs. Could I get a way without have a heading on it?

I like the idea of the consistency, but in most cases' you'll see the page title 3 times.
1)The Page Title.
2)The Navbar.
3)In the content.

Comment: +1. Page title is the most obvious way to orient the users. Also, it's good to top up the content that may appear in different contexts such as SEO. Google displays a preview of the content in their search. This was proven when I was doing some user testing for my application.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the context of the page.

Is the content self-evident? That is, if the nav item says "Activity", does the content make it clear that you're looking at activity items? For pages that are mostly copy, like you would see on a marketing site, page headers are great for wayfinding. A title can help users understand what they are reading before having to dive into 4 paragraphs of content. But in web apps where the content is very specific I'm not sure that adding a page title would be helpful.